# Can't set the value of TextAlign property through reflection

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, properties, controls

I've write a method that receives an own Class `HintProperties` with some properties and it's values, the property names of the `HintProperties` Class are taken by the method to find that the property exist in a control to set the control property value as the same which is set in the `HintProperties`.

This is the own Class:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines a text-hint and it's personalization properties.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class HintProperties

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets or sets the text-hint font.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <value>The font.</value>
        Public Property Font As Font = Nothing

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets or sets the text-hint.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property Text As String = String.Empty

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets or sets the text-hint color.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property Forecolor As Color = Color.Empty

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Gets or sets the text-hint alignment.
        ''' Only avaliable for specific controls such as Textbox's.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property TextAlign As HorizontalAlignment = 0

    End Class
```

And this is the method:

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Sets the properties of an specific control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Control">Indicates the Control.</param>
    ''' <param name="HintProperties">Indicates the properties to set it's values.</param>
    Private Shared Sub SetProperties(ByVal [Control] As Object,
                                     ByVal HintProperties As HintProperties)

        ' Set the hint-text.
        [Control].Text = HintProperties.Text

        Dim t As Type = [Control].GetType

        For Each Prop As Reflection.PropertyInfo In HintProperties.GetType.GetProperties

            Dim tprop As Reflection.PropertyInfo = t.GetProperty(Prop.Name)

            If Not tprop Is Nothing Then

                Try

                    If Not Prop.Name = "TextAlign" Then
                        tprop.SetValue([Control], Prop.GetValue(HintProperties, Nothing), Nothing)
                    Else
                        ' Here throws an unhandled System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception exception:
                        tprop.SetValue([Control], Prop.GetValue(HintProperties, Nothing), Nothing)

                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try

            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

The problem begins when in the `HandleCreated` event handler of a control I call the `SetProperties` method to pass an instance of `HintProperties` with the `TextAlign` property set as `HorizontalAlignment.Center` or `HorizontalAlignment.Right` I get an unhandled `win32` exception in the `SetProperties` method when I try to set the `TextAlign` property for example in a Textbox, I can find the property, I can't get the value, but I'm unable to set it.

In other words, I'm unable to set the `TextAlign` property of a control in the `handlecreated` event handler

Example:

```
    addhandler textbox1.handlecreated, addresof Control_HandleCreated

    Private Shared Sub Control_HandleCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim [Control] As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
        Dim [HintProperties] As HintProperties = ControlHints([Control]) ' A dictionary (of contorl, hintproperties)

         SetProperties([Control], [HintProperties])

        End Select

    End Sub
```

If I handle other events such as `Enter` or `Leave` there is no problem, but I need to set the `Textalign` property when the control is created.

What I'm doing wrong and how I can solve this?

Comment: not all TextAlign properties are of HorizontalAlignment type; Labels for instance have the same prop but are of ContentAlignment type (as is CheckBox).  That is not the case with TextBox but might cause problems elsewhere with other [Control]s

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the information then also I need to think how to improve it for other controls

Comment: HandleCreated is called when the control is first **shown** (see MSDN), which is pretty closely related to InitializeComponents in Sub New, so why not loop thru the controls there or in Form Load.  As long as it is set before shown is all you care, no?  You could use HandleCreated to fill a List<T> for the desired controls then process the list in Sub New/Form Load.